# How do I automate the setting of Cypress environment variables on a windows machine via a text file?

Tags: test-automation-framework, windows, cypress

On Unix and Mac machines, environmental variables can be read from .env files which have '*export*' commands in them.

For example:

```
export USER_ENV=test
export CLIENT=company
```

In windows, there's no such thing as the '*export*' command. I therefore use the '*set*' command to set the environmental variables.

```
set USER_ENV=test
set CLIENT=company
```

The problem is that I have to enter each and every line individually on the command prompt.
 Is there anyway I can run these 'set' commands to set the variables from a single test file?

This would save me the need to run each command individually from CMD.

I tried by entering the commands in a file *setenv.txt* and used the following command:


***cmd*** < ***setenv.txt***

That did not work as intended. I saw errors while trying to start Cypress.

How can I run these commands from a file via the CMD terminal in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a batch file where you set all your environment variables.

A batch file in Windows is just a text file with `.bat` extension, it could look like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

:: Assign all Path variables
SET TEST="some env value"
```

Then you execute it from the cmd:

```
C:\Users\PavelSaman\Desktop>echo %TEST%
%TEST%

C:\Users\PavelSaman\Desktop>env.bat

C:\Users\PavelSaman\Desktop>echo %TEST%
"some env value"
```

and you've set up what you previously did command by command.

You can also set a system environment variable via `setx` command with `/m` parameter:

```
:: add system environment variable (you need admin rights for this)
setx TEST2 "system environment" /m
```

You can find more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606419/set-windows-environment-variables-with-a-batch-file or here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx

Comment: Are all the three actions mentioned above necessary?

Comment: Well, you asked about "how to run these command from a file", so I answered mostly that. Another option how to set variables for Cypress is summed up here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Setting